Need Help with Importing Salesforce Schema for Custom Fields
I've created a custom picklist called Discount_Type__c within the Opportunity Product object. Despite using the appropriate schema import statements in my JavaScript code, I'm encountering difficulties retrieving the picklist values. Could you please review my code to identify any mistakes, or confirm if I'm using the correct schema?
    import { LightningElement,track,wire,api} from 'lwc';
    import { updateRecord, deleteRecord} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
    import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
    import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
    import { getObjectInfo, getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
    import OPPORTUNITY_PRODUCT_OBJECT  from '@salesforce/schema/OpportunityLineItem'; 
    import DISCOUNT_TYPE_FIELD  from '@salesforce/schema/OpportunityLineItem.Discount_Type__c'; 
    
    import getOpportunityLineItems from '@salesforce/apex/OpportunityLineItemController.getOpportunityLineItems';
    
    const columns = [
    { label: 'ProductLineItemName', fieldName: 'ProductLineItemName__c'},
    { label:'Quantity', fieldName:'Quantity',editable:true},
    { label: 'Sales Price', fieldName: 'UnitPrice', editable:true},
    { label: 'Discount Value', fieldName: 'Discount_Value__c', editable:true},
    {
        label: 'Discount Type',
        fieldName: 'Discount_Type__c',
        type: 'customPicklist',
        editable: true,
        typeAttributes: {
           
            options:{ fieldName:'pickListOptions'},
            value: {  fieldName: 'Discount_Type__c'},
            context:{ fieldName: 'Id'}
            
        }
    },
    { label: 'GST %', fieldName: 'GST__c', editable:true},
    
    
    {
        type: "button",
        typeAttributes: {
            iconName: "utility:delete",
            name: "deleteOpportunity",
            variant: "destructive",
            iconSize: "x-small",
            class: "small-button"
        }
    }
    
    ];
    
    export default class OpportunityLineItemsEditor extends LightningElement {
    
    @api recordId;
    
    opportunityLineData=[];
    columns = columns;
    draftValues=[];
    oppLineProp;
    discountTypeOptions=[];
    
        
    
    @wire(getOpportunityLineItems,{
        opportunityId:'$recordId',pickList:'$discountTypeOptions'
    }) getOpportunityLine(result){
        this.oppLineProp=result;
    
        if(result.data)
        {
            this.opportunityLineData=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.data));
            this.opportunityLineData=result.data.map((currItem) =>{
                let pickListOptions = this.discountTypeOptions;
                return {
                    ...currItem,
                      pickListOptions:pickListOptions
                      
                    //pickListOptions:picklistOptions
                };
                console.log('line87::' + JSON.stringify(this.opportunityLineData));
                    
            });
    
        }
        else if(result.error)
        {
            console.log('error while loading records');
        }
    
    
    }
    
    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: OPPORTUNITY_PRODUCT_OBJECT })
        opportunityProductInfo;
    
        @wire(getPicklistValues, {
            recordTypeId: '$opportunityProductInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId',
            fieldApiName: DISCOUNT_TYPE_FIELD
        })
        wiredPicklistValues({ data, error }) {
            if (data) {
                this.discountTypeOptions = data.values;
                console.log('piclistvalues::' + this.discountTypeOptions);
               
            } else if (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching picklist values', error);
            }
        }

I'm attempting to retrieve picklist values using getObjectInfo and getPicklistValues. For instance, I can successfully retrieve the picklist values for standard fields like 'Rating' in the 'Account' object. However, I encounter difficulties when trying to retrieve picklist values for custom fields. What would be the workaround to resolve this?

Please show how you are trying to retrieve the picklist values themselves. Just [edit] the question to add the detail.

Does this answer your question? LWC Get Pick-list Field Values
